# android sharedpreferences : nullPointerException

Tags: sharedpreferences

**hi, i am trying save information user after registration and when time app run , must be sent to main page but i do not want show Login Page ...**

[image]

**in class Register Activity :
note : this code is from RegisterActivity**

```
// for save status user
public void setSession(){
    // made model of sharePrefrence
   SharedPreferences  sp = getSharedPreferences(Key_SessionUsers,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Key_Status,true);
    editor.commit();

}
```

**in class Register LoginActivity :
 note  : "setSession()"  from registerActivity that call in  class LoginActivity .**

```
try {
    RegisterActivity registerActivity = new RegisterActivity();
    if (registerActivity.sp.getBoolean(registerActivity.Key_Status,false) == true){
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this , MainActivity.class));
    }

}catch (Exception e){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

> Error : nullPointerException .

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace to post?

Comment: That's not how to use `sharedPreferences`?

Comment: are you found problem in my question ? please tell me the  until, solve it.

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this method for save value in sharedPreferences and be worked good**

```
public void setSesstionUser(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(RegisterActivity.this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("Status_user", true);
    editor.apply();
```

// user is login then Status_user=>true

```
}
```

**this method can in put called any class .for example, i have Registration Activity and i wanna storing session to user after than registre user's information in server.. and still save in defualt sharePrefrence..
so when time storing user information to server , we should use `method '' setSesstionUser()`' into  storing sharePrefrence**

so finally be called in class that ...

```
   // check_state_user --------------------------------------------------------
    try {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
        boolean memberStatus = preferences.getBoolean("Status_user", false);
        if(memberStatus){ startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class)); finish();}

    }catch (Exception e){
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

this method help to us if  for login user in app is ok == > so going to main page

**picture**
1:
[image]

2:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
try {
    RegisterActivity registerActivity = new RegisterActivity();
    if (getSharedPreferences().getBoolean(registerActivity.Key_Status,false) == true){
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this , MainActivity.class));
    }

}catch (Exception e){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

because `sp` is not a public variable. The new part is `getSharedPreferences()` instead of `registerActivity.sp`.

Comment: why dont save 
are you have good way for save session user after than  registration -Axium

Comment: @oktay Because that's not how `SharedPreferences` work.

Comment: how to work shared Preference with Foreign class . are you know good way?

Comment: Foreign Class? As in?

Comment: you say using a Foreign Class is better?but i dont ues foregin class .are you good way for using sharedPreferences in foreign class

Comment: this isn't a foreign class. this is just getting a new version of a `SharedPreferences` object because the way you're doing it is not how it works.

Comment: Also, `SharedPreferences  sp = getSharedPreferences(Key_SessionUsers,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` equates to a new local variable, not your global `sp` variable, causing it to be null.

Comment: i find good way for save session . i use default Shared Preference and that problem is fix.

Comment: 'SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Status_user", flase);
        editor.apply();    '                                                                                                                   **this method for save value in sharedPreferences and be worked good**

Answer (score 0):

That is not how to retrieve data with SharedPreferences. You can get your boolean this way:

```
//Create and initialize your sharedpreferences object
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(Key_SessionUsers,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//get your boolean from the sharedpreferences object
boolean val = getSharedPreferences.getBoolean(registerActivity.Key_Status,false);
```

Since you have your boolean right after this, you can go ahead and do your comparisons.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!!

Comment: you know why send null pointer for me , because made sharedPreferences in Registration Activity that should save true and calling in loginActivity .. but i dont   find a good way